# Installing demo content via module.install file with Migrate module

Tags: migrations, features

I'm trying to import content on installation of my feature, but it's not happening.  If I enable the migrate_ui module and go and manually execute the import, then it imports fine.

The code below is from my module.install file, which was originally taken from the restaurant_event feature of the [Restaurant Distribution](https://www.drupal.org/project/restaurant).

```
/**
 * Implements hook_enable().
 */
function parcel_event_demo_enable() {
  Migration::registerMigration('ParcelEventMigrateEvent');
}

/**
 * Implements hook_disable().
 */
function parcel_event_demo_disable() {
  Migration::deregisterMigration('ParcelEventMigrateEvent');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I now understand that registering a migration is only registering it, not importing it, you still have to process the import.  I now call the `_panopoly_core_import_demo_content` function which executes `$migration->processImport();`

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Installation file for Parcel Event Demo
 */

/**
 * Implements hook_enable().
 */
function parcel_event_demo_enable() {
  Migration::registerMigration('ParcelEventMigrateEvent');
  _panopoly_core_import_demo_content(array('ParcelEventMigrateEvent'));
}

/**
 * Implements hook_disable().
 */
function parcel_event_demo_disable() {
  _panopoly_core_rollback_demo_content(array('ParcelEventMigrateEvent'));
  Migration::deregisterMigration('ParcelEventMigrateEvent');
}
```